# For Loop only taking last iteration when using FireStore

Tags: javascript, firebase, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to compare values in a Firebase/Firestore database, and I am changing a div border style based on if a value is true or not. The For loop goes through each time, but only keeps the last one. So it's rewriting over in the loop I guess, but I don't understand how?

```
// HANDLES THE FRONTEND TOGGLE/COLOR CHANGE OF SKILLS ON THE FRONTEND
for (var i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
    var toggledSkills = skills[i].id;
    console.log(toggledSkills);
    var query = db.collection('users').where(toggledSkills, "==", true);

    query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            // IF THE SKILL IS NOT LEARNED, PLAIN STYLING
            document.getElementById(toggledSkills).parentNode.style.border = "2px solid purple";
        } else {
            // IF THE SKILL IS TRUE/ALREADY LEARNED, COOL STYLING
            document.getElementById(toggledSkills).parentNode.style.border = "2px solid green";
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: you need to do for each on the querySnapshot. put that outside of your for i loop

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, the query snapshot would need the "query" variable, which is recreated after each iteration of the for loop. So the querySnapshot wouldn't have the "query" variable to work with if it was on the outside, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting more than one element, you should go through all the list with forEach.

Something like this:

```
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

You can find more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result, last div style is being changed, the rest are staying standard. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Chance can you add the code with the foreach to your question?